# Two rook problems

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I was thinking about chess problems and I couldn't find an answer for these. Are those open? If yes, how good upper or lower bounds are known?

How many rooks one can put in a normal $8\times 8$ board such that every rook threatens exactly 2 other rooks?

How many rooks one can put in a normal $8\times 8$ board such that every rook is threatened by odd number of other rooks?

Comment: Do you know the answer to this question?

Comment: No. That is why I asked for a help.

Comment: Some people ask questions that they already know the answer to.  Your question didn't say one way or the other, so I thought I'd find out for sure.

Comment: Okay. Well, I edited the question to be clearer that I don't know the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is good to ask both questions in a general way:
How many rooks one can put in a normal $8×8$ board such that every rook threatens exactly $k$ other rooks?

If $k=1$ then the lower bound for the number of rooks is 2. But for the upper bound, we must find different pairs that mutually threaten each other. So we can locate 4 pairs or 8 rooks on the board.

If $k=2$ (your first question) then the lower bound is 4. I think the upper bound is 30, where we put a rook on the margin squares (a and h columns and 1,8 rows).

Now I prove that $k$ can not exceed $2$. Indeed if $k \ge 3$ then every rook must be in the middle of two other rooks in a row or column which is impossible (note  that this must happen for all rooks in the board).